# Access Denied to folder have full permission

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions

I'm working on document viewer web application and I use Atalasfot third party Library, the "WebImageViewer" control from the library needs to specify folder which he will use it to get list of images, so I create "Images" folder in my application and I give it full control permission like in the following screen shot :

[image]

also there is permission for IIS_IUSERS not appear in the upper image.

when I run the application I get the following Error :

```
   Access to the path 'XXX\Images' is denied. ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested     resource. Consider granting access rights to     the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: where you set the image path in your code? can you update question with related code?

Comment: There is no code for setting image, it's only an attribute in the control and all the writing and reading done internally by the control

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem stems from leaving `'Anonymous Access' checked in IIS`, even with the username/password you provided for the anonymous user.

**Solution:-** You need to un-check `anonymous user` and use '`Integrated Windows Authentication'`

Comment: Thanks for fast reply Rahul, but how to do this in development Sever?

Comment: Didnt get that properly, you need to go to the IIS and change the setting there!

Comment: I am not quite sure about that but the best possible reason for this error is what I have mentioned in my answer. Anyways trying to find out if something else is also possible!